# Cannot delete files inside K8s container within mounted Azure File Share

Tags: linux, azure, kubernetes, azure-blob-storage, azure-aks

I have a problem when deleting files inside container.
Here is the command I execute via kubectl:

```
kubectl exec mypod-7ddbbb6c87-cwl76 -- ls -lat /usr/bin/myprogram/logs
-rwxrwxrwx 1 1000 1000   186446 Oct 22 12:59 mylogfile.log

kubectl exec mypod-7ddbbb6c87-cwl76 -- find /usr/bin/myprogram/logs -type f -mtime +14 -delete
find: cannot delete '/usr/bin/myprogram/logs/mylogfile.log': No such file or directory
```

I cannot understand what is the problem?

This directory /usr/bin/myprogram/logs is volume mount of Azure File Share.
This AzureFileShare is used for multiple deployments\pods therefore PV is ReadWriteMany
Here the part of my Yaml configuration

```
    kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: mypod-logs
provisioner: kubernetes.io/azure-file
reclaimPolicy: Retain
allowVolumeExpansion: true
parameters:
  skuName: Standard_LRS
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mypod-logs
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: mypod-logs
  azureFile:
    secretName: '#{AzureFileShareSecretName}'
    shareName: mypod-logs
    readOnly: false
  mountOptions:
  - dir_mode=0777
  - file_mode=0777
  - uid=1000
  - gid=1000
  - mfsymlinks
  - nobrl
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mypod-logs
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: mypod-logs
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
---
volumeMounts:
    - readOnly: false
      mountPath: /usr/bin/myprogram/logs
      name: mypod-logs
volumes:
    - name: mypod-logs
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: mypod-logs
```

Answer (score 0):

All the things work fine on my side as the screenshot below shows:

[image]

But I met the same issue before. You can try to execute the command like this:

```
kubectl exec mypod-7ddbbb6c87-cwl76 -- bash -c "find /usr/bin/myprogram/logs -type f -mtime +14 -delete"
```

Comment: `kubectl exec mypod-7ddbbb6c87-cwl76 -- bash -c "find /usr/bin/myprogram/logs -type f -mtime +14 -delete"`
Same error...

Comment: @user261226 Can you run the command `df -h` in that pad and show the output?

Comment: `//myfileshareBlob.file.core.windows.net/myprogram-logs  100T  3.1G  100T   1% /usr/bin/myprogram/logs`

Comment: Also here the mount point
`//myfileshareBlob.file.core.windows.net/myprogram-logs on /usr/bin/myprogram/logs type cifs (rw,relatime,vers=3.0,cache=strict,username=myfileshareBlob,domain=,uid=1000,forceuid,gid=1000,forcegid,addr=55.255.44.18,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,soft,persistenthandles,nounix,serverino,mapposix,nobrl,mfsymlinks,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1)`

Comment: @user261226 It seems everything is ok. Do you go inside the pod and check if there is something wrong?

Comment: Yes. Nothing strange inside pod.
Also `rm -f /usr/bin/myprogram/logs/mylogfile.log` executed without any error - but file remained untouched.